# Accessing Objects C++

Tags: c++, class

Well I think this might be a very easy Question but I still don't know what I'm doing wrong.
This is my problem:

I have 3 classes, lets call them A,B and C

a.h

```
class A
{
    public:
    B *b_object;
    C *c_object;
}
```

a.cpp

```
A()
{
   b_object = new B;
   c_object = new C;
}
```

so we actually have two objects, one of b and c when we create an object of a.

b.h

```
#include "a.h"
```

class B is also including the a.h but i can't access the c_object form the b_object like

```
c_object->do_stuff();
```

Why is this not working? I thought with *c_object is created on heap and through the #include "a.h" in b.h I should be able to access it.

Well thanks in advance,
Sammy

Comment: Where are you trying to access the c_object from? From inside the B object?

Comment: "access the c_object form the b_object" ? isn't c_object part of class `A`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using pointers and dynamic memory allocation instead of just embedding `b_object` and `c_object` as members of `A`? Also, you're missing a semicolon at the end of `class A`, is this a typo or is it actually what you have in your code?

Comment: You've omitted the bits that don't work. Please post an SSCCE.

Comment: can you post the line of code which you are having problems with? or better yt the whole snippet? right now you only show how class A looks like but you have problems with class C; so please go into a bit more detail

Comment: @Tushar yes inside the B object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), which is a major feature of C++ and Object-Oriented Languages in general.

Since your c_object is defined **inside** the A class, it can only be accessed by an A object (unless you specify otherwise).

Your b_object is also in the A class, but that doesn't mean it can access the c_object. For example, let the b_object be the door of a car and the c_object be the tires. The car itself is the a_object. Just because a car has both a door and some tires doesn't mean the door should be able to make the tires do something. Only the car is able to access both.

Comment: Well I think I found my specific problem which had something to do with signals and slots in Qt. But my question is still the same. Lets stick to your car example. Is it possible to let the door access the tires and let them do something? (sounds kind of silly but you get the point)

Comment: @SeriousSammy It's possible, but it defeats the purpose of encapsulation. Encapsulation ensures that any random classes can't access/modify the contents of your class. If you want the door to access the tires, maybe you should consider some other design. Perhaps the car can ask the door (call on some function on object b) whether it should do an action on the tires (if the function returns true, then call another function on object c).

Comment: you're right, it's actually a bad idea to have the door access the tires. But it would be possible through pointers right? (Well I'm not gonna do it this way, i already fix my issue)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you have circular dependency in the problem:
    1) B.h is included in A.h.
    2) A.h is included in B.h.

because A needs to know members of B to initialize its B pointer and B needs to know the members of A to do whatever it is you are trying to accomplish. Thus creating circular dependency.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Also, just because you included A.h in B.h doesn't mean you have access to A's data members. You would have to have an existing object A (inside of B) for you to access the pointer C.

Or you can make it so that B is a derived class of A, so B will inherit the private data members of A, which will then allow you to access pointer C.

Comment: No the circular dependency was not the issue. I want to know if A has two objects b and c, is it possible that b can access c? Or like Tushar above said, is it possible for the door to access the tires?

Comment: @Serious Sammy - Are you trying to say that since class A contains an object B, that object B should be able to access object C? If so, the answer is no. Also, it is possible for the door to access the tires, but it goes against the principle of encapsulation.